# text-align:center doesn't perfect center my Font Awesome icon

Tags: html, css, position, font-awesome

I would like to center the arrow-down icon from Font Awesome in my div `#first`. `name` is centered, `descr` too, but when I want to center the content of `arrow`, it doesn't work..

Here's my HTML :

```
<div id="first">
    <div class="name">My Name</div>
    <div class="descr">Web Dev</div>
    <div class="arrow">
        <a class="scrollTo" href="#second">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-4x"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS :

```
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#252932;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
}

#first
{
    margin:0 90px 0 90px;
    height:100vh;
    background:#252932;
}

#first .name
{
    padding-top: 25vh;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:10vh;
    text-align: center;
}

#first .descr
{
    color:#195962;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4vh;
}

.arrow
{
    text-align:center;
}

.arrow i
{
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:80px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
```

I would like to fix the arrow on the bottom of the page, that's why I use `position:absolute; bottom:80px`. But it seems these properties broke my display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        *, *:before, *:after {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        html{
            height:100%;
        }

        body
        {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            background:#252932;
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            font-weight:400;
        }

        #first
        {
            margin:0 90px 0 90px;
            min-height:100%;
            background:#252932;
            display:relative;
        }

        #first .name
        {
            padding-top: 25vh;
            color:#fff;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size:10vh;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #first .descr
        {
            color:#195962;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 4vh;
        }

        .arrow
        {

            background-color:blue;
            position: absolute;
            bottom:80px;
            left: 50%;
            display: block;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            margin-left: -40px;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .arrow a{
            display:block;
        }

        .arrow i
        {
            color:#fff;
            background-color:red;
            transition:all 0.5s ease;
            line-height:80px;
            text-align:center;

        }
```

Comment: I just added position and bottom as you had in your code. Tell me another thing. Does your fixed element( .arrow) has a  width and height?

Comment: No it doesn't have. I'm just using a `div .arrow` in order to center the text into itself.

Comment: I´ve updated the code. The <i> should have relative position, because it´s wrapped by an absolute element. Then display as block and width:100% should do the job.

Comment: Work perfectly, and responsive :)
But .. thanks to `margin-left: -40px;` right ?

Comment: Yes... this values should reflect half of the element width!!! :) You are always welcome!!! :)

Comment: Ah, and a small suggestion... IMO you should wrapp .name and .descr with a div... it´s easier if you want, in the future, positioning these elements!!! :)

Comment: About the last thing, you're right, my example was a little try, and I will refactor my HTML code, and reduce my CSS :D

Comment: Yes... i understood that your css was just a try!! :)